# convertir consulta sql a linq utilizacion agrupacion y order by

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Que tal amigos estoy queriendo convertir la siguiente consulta sql a linq

```
select a.MtoProcedimientoId,
       a.Ejercicio,
       a.NoLicitacion,
       c.RazonSocial,
       b.RfcProveedor,
       sum(b.MontoContrato) as monto,
       SUM(1) AS Numero 
from MtoProcedimiento a
left join MtoContrato b  on b.MtoProcedimientoId=a.MtoProcedimientoId
left join MtoProveedor c on c.MtoProveedorId=b.MtoProveedorId
where Ejercicio=2020
group by a.MtoProcedimientoId,
         a.Ejercicio,
         a.NoLicitacion,
         c.RazonSocial,
         b.RfcProveedor
```

sera posible que me echen una mano.

muchas gracias

Comment: chale, te ayudaría pero no se linq :(

Comment: Como mapeaste las entidades? porque `linq to sql` ya no existe, imagino esta usando `entity framework`, no? si es asi la relaciones entre estas entidades, las defines?

Comment: que tal Leandro es correcto estoy usando entityframework; y las relaciones estan definidas dentro de cada  model por citar un ejemplo en el modelo MtoProcedimiento la relacion con  MtoContrato la hago asi. Para MtoProcedimientos   public virtual ICollection<MtoContrato> MtoContratos { get; set; } y para Mtocontrato public virtual MtoProcedimiento MtoProcedimiento { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser algo como esto

```
var query = from a in _dbcontext.MtoProcedimiento 
             join b in _dbcontext.MtoContrato on a.MtoProcedimientoId equals b.MtoProcedimientoId into gC
             join c in _dbcontext.MtoProveedor on b.MtoProveedorId equals c.MtoProveedorId 
            where a.Ejercicio = 2020
            select new NombreClass() 
            {
                ProcedimientoId = a.MtoProcedimientoId,
                Ejercicio = a.Ejercicio,
                NoLicitacion = a.NoLicitacion,
                RazonSocial = c.RazonSocial,
                RfcProveedor = b.RfcProveedor,
                Monto = gC.Sum(x=> x.MontoContrato),
            }
```

Estoy aplicando esta tecnica de agrupar joins

[Realizar combinaciones agrupadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

Y debes crear la clase

```
public class NombreClass
{
     public int ProcedimientoId {get; set;}
     public int Ejercicio {get; set;}
     public string RazonSocial {get; set;}
     //otras propiedades
}
```